# Vue.js - pass variable as property to nested child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a question about passing variables to nested components.

I have 3 components:

1. Parent
2. Child
3. SubChild

and they have a shared variable (call it **myVar**).

Suppose I don't want to use Vuex. My question is what is a better way of passing **myVar** from **Parent** to **SubChild**.

### First way

1. (In Parent) I am passing **myVar** to **Child** by props option. (it's common).
2. (In Child) I am passing the prop option **myVar** directly to SubChild as its prop option.

### Second way

1. (In Parent) I am passing **myvar** to **Child** by props option. (it's common).
2. (In Child) I am cloning the prop option **myVar** to local variable (call it **myLocalVar**) and passing the cloned variable **myLocalVar** to SubChild as its prop option.

I prefer the second way, but I have to create watches

1. To handle changes from **Parent** to **myLocalVar**.
2. To handle changes from **Child** to emit it to **Parent**.

Comment: I don't see where the question of your question is, but, if your aplication grows, it's better to use Vuex. Other than that the first way looks more clean, but can be dificult to watch the changes and pass it to parents/childs.

Comment: imo you should use vuex, or create a mixin that has a Vue.observable object in data, then all which import the mixin would have a shared object, props are for component options not data, both your options will bloat the components with input/output logic for the prop

Comment: [Provide / inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#provide-inject)

Answer (score 2):

To do this you can use [provide/inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html). Your parent would provide data like this:

```
provide: {
    user: 'John Doe'
  }
```

And your nested child would use it like this:

```
inject: ['user']
```

Nethertheless you should really use `Vuex` for this.

Answer (score 2):

I would have written this as a comment, but I don't have enough "reputation".

As Mael pointet out in his/her comment, your posting does not contain a question. You are merely describing two (working) implementation patterns.

Assuming that you want to know which of it is a better choice I would say:

I'd prefer the "First way" as it's cleaner and needs less code.

The "Second way" seems only be useful when you need to map the property to a different value for the SubChild.

But in this case I would not use watchers. Instead use a computed value that you can pass to the SubChild as a property.

Whenever the property given by the Parent is changed the computed value in the Child should be recalculated and thus trigger the SubChild re-render.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pass it all you should have a callback function in the parent that can change the state *in* the parent. The *only* place you should actually have state is the parent.

Then you can pass this function as props as far down as you want (or as noted here provide/inject), this way you have 1 place you keep your state and 1 function that changes it. Any event that should change the state will call the callback and it will change at the parent level.